# Truncate (not round) decimal places in sprintf?

Tags: perl, printf, mod-perl

I want to display the dollar value with two digits after the decimal point to denote the cents. In the below program the output is 23.24.  Perl rounds the decimal places. How to avoid it.  I want the output to be 23.23.

```
$val=23.2395;
$testa=sprintf("%.2f", $val);
print "\n$testa\n $val";
```

Comment: You want it to always truncate?

Comment: Calculate in pennies instead of dollars, and then use `int` to truncate fractional pennies.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
print int(23.2395*100)/100;  # => 23.23
```

Comment: No need for the `printf` decorum

Answer (score 7):

[Math::Round](https://metacpan.org/module/Math::Round) has different rounding methods.

```
use Math::Round 'nlowmult';
print nlowmult( 0.01, 23.2395 ); # 23.23
```